Submit too many commands from different files as a single batch job
I want to use bash to run a batch job on an HPC. The commands to be executed are saved to a text file. Previously, I used the following to run each line of the text file separately as a batch job.
File=Commands.txt
head -n $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID $File | tail -n 1 | bash

I need to extend this approach to find all files in a certain directory (and their single level descendants) that follow a certain pattern
BaseDir="Folder1/Folder2/Folder3" 
FolderPattern="FolderPattern*" 
FilePatterns=("FilePattern1_*.txt" "FilePattern2_*.txt")

There should be multitple candidate folders, in each there should be at least single file of each pattern. I need to read the lines in these files, without saving them to a file. The combined commands should be distributed into 210 maximum batch jobs. For example, if there are 1000 commands to be execured, there should be ~ 5 commands to run sequentially in each batch job.
I need to ensure that the loaded HPC modules and python location is inherited in all running jobs:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --account=XXXX
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --job-name=Process
#SBATCH --output=%x-%A-%a.out
#SBATCH --error=%x-%A-%a.err
#SBATCH --partition=XXX
#SBATCH --time=00:30:00
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=200G
#SBATCH --gpus-per-node=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --array=1-210
#SBATCH --export=ALL

# Load required modules
module load tensorflow

# Ensure the virtual environment paths are correctly set as environment variables.
export PATH=TF_Virt_Env/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=TF_Virt_Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

# Activate the Python virtual environment
source TF_Virt_Env/bin/activate

Example commands
/usr/bin/time -v python3 Script.py --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2 --arg3 val3 

Is this possible without splitting the commands to separate files and submit them separately.
Thanks in advance

Do you want to write that in Bash or Python?
